# Input type date not updating React

Tags: reactjs

I have an input with type date inside a form as below:

```
<Input type="date" defaultValue={this.state.todayDate} onChange={this.handleChangeDate}/> // defaultValue contains today's date
```

However, when changing the date from the current date (today's date), the state won't be updated and the whole item can't be saved upon submission of the form. This is the handleChangeDate method:

```
handleChangeDate(event) {
        let item = {...this.state.item};
        item.timeStamp = event.target.value; // Update time stamp in item
        this.setState({item: item}); // Update item in state
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change defaultValue to value:

```
<Input type="date" value={this.state.item.timeStamp} onChange={this.handleChangeDate}/> // defaultValue contains today's date
```